# How to update a value of p (Paragraph tag) using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to  update the value of the P tag on change of drop down menu using jquery. 
My code for changing and getting value using jquery is as follows. Please give some solutions thanks...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
    alert($(this).text());

  });
});
</script>

 <p id="qtitle" style="padding-left:15px;"><strong>text to change</strong></p>
```

Comment: `$("#qtitle strong").html("YourNewText")`

Comment: Sorry for that mistake but how can i change the p value dynamically.

Comment: "*Dynamically*" based on what, what changes do you want to make, and when?

Comment: $("#qtitle strong").html("YourNewText") solve my problem Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
        $("#qtitle strong").html($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<p id="qtitle" style="padding-left:15px;"><strong>text to change</strong></p>

<div id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>
    <li><a>3</a></li>
    <li><a>4</a></li>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
    $('#qtitle strong').text($(this).text());
 });
```

.html(text) works, too. However .text(text) is a secure way to alter the text value of elements. Check out the doc at http://api.jquery.com/text/

See the working code at:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnAEh/3/)

Answer (score 1):

**Please replace your code as**

```
  document.ready(function(){
      $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
        $("#qtitle strong").html($("#YourNewText").val());
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<select class="target">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<p id="qtitle" style="padding-left:15px;"><strong>Text to change</strong></p>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
    $("#qtitle strong").html($(".target option:selected").text());
});
```

Demo in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/anikcse/GS7ms/) jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu li a').click(function(){
        $("#qtitle strong").html($(this).text());
    });
});
```

```css
ul.dropdown-menu li a{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <p id="qtitle" style="padding-left:15px;"><strong>text to change</strong></p>

    <ul id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a>Test 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Test 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Test 3</a></li>
        <li><a>Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```